# Remove the 'NUL' character in SSIS being imported from a text file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an input file that is generated from an external source on a daily basis, so I have littel control ovever it. 
The file is to be read by SSIS and then inserted into a SQL Server 2012 database. I have come to issue on one particular line.

The line in questions looks like this:

```
"|"James"|"Done"|""|""|""|"11548"|" "|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"
```

The value in the 7th field is not actually a space, but a 'NUL' character ASCII(0)  and I seem to be unable
to remove it witin SSIS.

I'm using a derived column transform to replace the null.  The whole string is named as "DataColumn".  So far I have tried the following in the expression builder.

```
1) Replace(DataColumn, "CHAR(0)", "")
2) Replace(DataColumn, "CHAR(0)", "\"\"")
3) Replace(DataColumn, "ASCII(0), "")
4) Replace(DataColumn, " ", "")
5) Replace(DataColumn, "\x000", "")
```

In addition, the following suggestions have also been tried:

```
Replace(DataColumn, "0x0", "")
Replace(DataColumn, "\x0000", "")
```

To date none seem to be working for me, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't quote the function calls. If you do, it's looking for a literal string like 'CHAR(0)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling the `REPLACE` function, don't quote the calls to the `CHAR` or `ASCII` functions. If you quote them, then `REPLACE` is looking for a literal string with the value `CHAR(0)` for example.

This example here strips out a NULL character

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'Hello>' + char(0) + '<'
declare @fixed varchar(100) = replace(@str, char(0), '')

select @str, len(@str), @fixed, len(@fixed)
```

Sidenote: The `ASCII` function returns the numeric codepint for a character, so that's not what you're after here since you know you're looking for the null character at point 0

Comment: Just tried that, however removing the quotes in SSIS expression builder, causes a "The function "char" was not recognized. Either the function name is incorrect or does not exist." error message.  I tried both char(0) and CHAR(0).  

Thanks for pointing out the side note btw.  Something to remember.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realise `CHAR` isn't supported in SSIS. Try: `REPLACE(DataColumn, 0x0, '')`. Either that, or use `\x0000` (four zeroes) in your search string.

Comment: Both 

    "\x0000"
    \x0000 
threw error messages. 

    replace(DataColumn, "0x0", "") ran to completion, but the original problem still manifested

Comment: Would it be practical to import this data into a temporary table, fix it, then import to the destination table?

Comment: According to this http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2010/01/27/handling-ssis-expressions-with-literal-strings/ you should indded use `\x0000`. What error message did you get when you used that?

Comment: There's also `HEX` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141812.aspx. Try `HEX(0)`

Comment: Both "HEX(0)" and HEX(0) produced the original problem - at least on my system. So for any readers, who might have a similar problem, I've updated my original question to reflect these as attempts.

Comment: I am marking @mroach's idea as the answer for two reasons: 1) mroach has made me aware of the fact that expression evaluation at the
Sql Server level seems to be more  versatile than within SSIS.  2) mroach's  suggestion about using a temporary table should do the trick with the original CHAR(0) suggestion

Comment: Thanks to all for  your suggestions

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution but you never posted any actual error messages or description of the outcome. None of the samples you posted in your question are going to do what you expect because they are all string literals. If you decide to go the T-SQL route with this you _still_ need to understand what a string literal is or you will come up with the same problem.